# Does "TMS Recurring Billing Solution" being enabled on a Merchant Account stop the SOAP API from working?

Tags: soap, payment-gateway, recurring-billing, cybersource

For some background, we had built an integration with the CyberSource so that users could process one time and recurring payments from within our application. We integrate with the REST API for one time payments, and the SOAP API for recurring payments.

A customer of ours has stated that they were asked by CyberSource to move to a new merchant account with the "TMS Billing Solution" enabled. After doing so, the REST API calls are still working as expected, but the SOAP API calls no longer work with this merchant.

Does "TMS Recurring Billing Solution" being enabled on a Merchant Account stop the SOAP API from working?

I advised them to regenerate the Transaction Key needed for the SOAP API, and try again. Still if anyone knows, some help would be greatly appreciated. We would like not to have to build a new integration because of this change if possible.

Comment: Hi Dylan are you able to share the error returned by Cybersource? I suspect either tokenization is not enabled or your tokens were not migrated to the new account, but will need the error message to be sure.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for helping with this. The specific error the client is seeing is ReasonCode 150 "General System failure". The integration we had build for this client does not currently use tokenization. Since they updated to this TMS merchant account, I was wondering if the integration we built will still work, or if we now will have to build in the tokenization support due to the merchant account change.

Comment: Ok, I will need a bit more info. Do you have the request ID for a failed transaction?

Comment: Hi Will, I have asked the client for this information. My worry is that we are seeing a general system failure error, so it's possible that the transaction won't show up in CyberSource admin for them. I do have a question while I await their reply. Does the SOAP API need to be enabled on an account? I was thinking it's possible since they switched merchant accounts that this functionality could be disabled, and that could be why we are seeing a general error.

Comment: I was able to get the request ID for a failed transaction from the customer. The ID is: 6330290020686535804276. The customer also mentioned the following about this transaction: "After we tried the recurring donation, we looked in CyberSource, and the donation showed up in the “transactions” section, but it did not “settle” and did not create a subscription for the subsequent payments."

Comment: Another note since I don't think I had mentioned it. The way our integration is currently setup is it will attempt a one time payment through the REST API, and then it will create the subscription based on that transaction ID using the SOAP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling "TMS Recurring Billing Solution" does not stop the SOAP API from working.

Your Cybersource account is not enabled for recurring billing. See the screenshot with for the transaction with request ID 6330290020686535804276.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrmk0.png)

Comment: Hi Will, I appreciate the feedback. I will let the client know that Recurring Billing will need to be enabled on their account. Thanks so much!